Is there a source for Hashem loving Rashayim
People sometimes say  that  Hashem even  loves Rashayim. Is there is a source in Chazal for that?
There seem to be sources that say the oppisite: To give but one example. The Rambam Hilchos Teshuva 7:6 says about a Baal Teshuva    בִּ. הַתְּשׁוּבָה מְקָרֶבֶת אֶת הָרְחוֹקִים. אֶמֶשׁ הָיָה זֶה שָׂנאוּי לִפְנֵי הַמָּקוֹם
מְשֻׁקָּץ וּמְרֻחָק וְתוֹעֵבָה. וְהַיּוֹם הוּא אָהוּב וְנֶחְמָד קָרוֹב
וְיָדִיד Previously, this person was hated by God, disgusting, far removed, and abominable. Now, he is beloved and desirable, close, and dear.
The Rambam seems to be clearly saying that Hashem hates Rashayim. While his hatred is not the personal animus of wishing ill on a person in general and he only wants the person to do teshuva and become beloved, as long as the person chooses not to, Hashem hates him.
Where  are the sources that Hashem loves such a person even the way he is ?

Why would Hashem be רוצה בתשובה otherwise?

It sounds like you are assuming a limitation and that Gd cannot simultaneously "hate" and "love" someone
